# Group error in library

Tags: view, grouping

I have created a view in a library for field `Status`. The options for this field are

```
In progress, 
Pending,
Resolved
```

After applying this I can see that grouping happens based on 4 options

```
In progress(10 values), 
Pending(5 values), 
Pending (1 value), 
Resolved(50 values).
```

Can anyone explain why grouping occurs twice on `Pending`?

Answer (score 2):

The `Pending (1 value)` seems to have a trailing whitespace, while `Pending(5 values)` has not. Thus, the values are treated as different.

If you change the value of that item to `Pending` (without whitespace), the grouping should work as expected.

Comment: As a good practice to avoid this, don't use a standard text field. Where you want users to choose from a limited choice of values, use either a choice field (if you're fairly sure the possible values won't change often), or a lookup field with another list containing the status values.

Comment: there is no whitespace. I am using choice field

Comment: When changing / renaming the values of a choice field, the values that already have been used, **won't get updated**. For example: 1. `Pending ` was accidently written with trailing whitespace. 2. Someone assigned that status to an item. 3. Someone else recognized that there is a typo in `Pending ` and fixed it. 4. The "wrong" `Pending ` is **not** updated at the specific icon. Have you tried changing the status from `Pending ` to something else and back to `Pending` again?

Comment: tried that but does not work

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the scenario to your initial question? A picture is worth a thousand words. :-) Maybe that provides new clues.

Answer (score 0):

**Pending (1 value)** seems has a space at the end while **Pending(5 value)** doesn't so it considered as a different status.